# R Shiny Data Table and Plot not appearing, no errors thrown

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

So I've been experimenting with Shiny, and while my the input portions of my UI are fine, I'm having some issues on the back end. I'm having no errors produced, but am just getting a blank screen.  Here's the jist of the UI.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
   fluidRow(
      column(3,
       wellPanel(
         h4('Weights'),
         ##Various Inputs here that work fine
        )
      ),
     column(9,
         plotlyOutput("plotMain"),
         dataTableOutput('testTable')
      )
    )
)
```

Now there exists a data frame name fbb.data which is just your run of the middle data frame.  This interacts with weights and other various inputs from above.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  selected.data <- reactive({
    cbind(fbb.data[,c(input$xvar, 'player','prim.pos')],
          Value = valvar(),
          Price = costvar() )
  })

  weight.server <- reactive({
    c(input$w.fg, input$w.ft, input$w.3pm, input$w.reb, input$w.ast,     input$w.stl, input$w.blk, input$w.pts)
    })

  valvar <- reactive({
    rowSums(fbb.data[,which(names(fbb.data) == "fg.r"):which(names(fbb.data) == "pts.r")] * weight.server())
  })

  costvar <- reactive({
valvar()/sum(valvar()[1:(input$num.teams*input$rost.size)])*((input$doll.per - input$doll.min)*input$num.teams)
  })

  output$testTable <- renderDataTable(selected.data)


  output$plotMain <- renderPlotly({
    p <- ggplot(selected.data(), aes(x = input$xvar , y = Price, shape = prim.pos)) + geom_point()
    ggplotly(p)
  })
```

I would understand if there was some issue with the ploting, but I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on with the table.

Comment: Where did you get this function `wellPanel`?

Comment: From the Shiny tutorial. 
 https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.11/wellPanel.html

Comment: I think there is a problem with your fbb.data somewhere along the line. I have a solution with a non-reactive fbb.data frame (I can post below but would need reproducible code to investiate further) which works once you change the shape argument from shape=prim.pos to shape=factor(prim.pos). Does your testTable look right? You may need to change renderDataTable(selected.data) to renderDataTable(selected.data())

Comment: you have an extra comma in **h4('Weights'),** and missing **}** at the end of your server function

Comment: I would assume that your issue is in the `cbind()` statement, but it's impossible to tell without having the `fbb.data` frame and/or your full code.